# convert WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec to JSON object

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

I have test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class PaymentsITest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient client1;


    @Test
    public void getPayment() {
        client1.get().uri("/v1/payments/123" )
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.group_header.identification").exists()
                .jsonPath("$.group_header.date_time").exists()
                .jsonPath("$.response").exists()
        ;
    }
}
```

I need to check the properties inside the `response` object.
Is there any way to convert the `WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec` which returned by the methode `expectBody()` into JSON object or JSON String ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it 
Using `expectBody().returnResult().getResponseBody()` it will return the response as `byte[]` then convert the `byte[]` into string

```
    String s=new String(client1.get().uri("/v1/payments/123" )
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectBody().returnResult().getResponseBody());

    System.out.println(s);
```